# Having difficulty adding elements to 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
Mathematics:MTH105
Science:SCI205
Computer Science:CPS301
...
```

And I have an assignment that requires that I read file and place each line into an array that should look like this:

```
subjectsArray[][] = {
   {"Mathematics", "MTH105"},
   {"Science", "SCI205"},
   {"Computer Science", "CPS301"}
};
```

I am getting a compile error when I attempt to add the contents of the file to a 2-dimensional array:

```
private static String[][] getFileContents(File file) {

    Scanner scanner = null;
    ArrayList<String[][]> subjectsArray = new ArrayList<String[][]>();

    //Place the contents of the file in an array and return the array
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(file);
        int i = 0;

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {

            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] lineSplit = line.split(":");

            for(int j = 0; j < lineSplit.length; j++) {
                subjectsArray[i][j].add(lineSplit[0]); //The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String[][]>
            }

            i++;
        }
        return subjectsArray;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Error reads:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String[][]>
```

I am new to multi-dimensional arrays and not sure what it is I'm doing wrong. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When you're asking a question about an error in your code, it would be smart and helpful to post the full error message, and indicate in your code which line causes it. Seems kind of obvious that you should include this information, no?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I did: subjectsArray[i][j].add(lineSplit[0]); //The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<String[][]>

Comment: @NicholasLaw It's usually a good idea to put that outside of your code so readers don't have to go hunting for it.

Comment: @user3580294 Error added after java code

Comment: @NicholasLaw Also, do you know how long the file is?

Comment: @user3580294 No. The other half of the assignment is to add/delete subjects to the file, so it could 0, 1 or more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is the selection of the type for the result: this type

```
ArrayList<String[][]>
```

represents a three-dimensional structure - a list of 2D arrays. What you need is a two-dimensional structure, e.g.

```
ArrayList<String[]>
```

So the first fix is this:

```
List<String[]> subjectsArray = new ArrayList<String[]>(); // Note the type on the left: it's an interface
```

Once this is done, the rest of the code flows by itself: you do not need the inner `for` loop, it gets replaced by a single line:

```
subjectsArray.add(lineSplit);
```

The final fix is the `return` line: you need to convert the `List<String[]>` to `String[][]`, which can be done by calling `toArray()`, like this:

```
return subjectsArray.toArray(new String[subjectsArray.size()][]);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `toArray()` return an `Object[]` whose elements were `String[]`?

Comment: @user3580294 You're right, I need to put the result array. Thanks!

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for your help. I changed to this `ArrayList<String[][]> contentsArray = new ArrayList<String[]>();` like you suggested but now I get this error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<String[]> to ArrayList<String[][]>`. Can you help?

Comment: @NicholasLaw Oops, I copy-pasted the old type on the left. Please see the edit.

Comment: Thanks again @dasblinkenlight However, it seems now I get an error in the return statement you suggested: `Cannot specify an array dimension after an empty dimension`. I'm assuming this because I need to do this: `return subjectsArray.toArray(new String[subjectsArray.size()][]);` istead of what you have suggested. Is that right? This Method is this only thing holding me up from completing this assignment and it's really frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use an ArrayList method on a String. I am not sure that is possible. The simplest way to do what you need I think is:

```
for(int j = 0; j < lineSplit.length; j++) {
            subjectsArray[i][j]=lineSplit[j]; 
        }
```